# Avoiding multiple queries to display model data on Django admin

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

I am using Django amdin for one of my data models. I want to display customized values on admin UI for each model.
On db, the result of a single query runs as multiple queries on django admin, one for each row 
I am trying to avoid that.

Here are my models:

```
class words(models.Model):
    word_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    word=models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.word,self.word_id)

class meanings(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    word_id=models.ForeignKey(words,on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='word_id')
    meaning=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s  %s  %d ' % ( self.spelling_id.spelling,self.meaning,self.id)
```

For the second model, while loading the page, for each row I saw there are  2 queries running one on words table and other on meanings table. (from debug toolbar)

I tried avoiding that by using the below option.

models.py:

```
class meanings(models.Model):
    meaning_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    word_id=models.ForeignKey(words,on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='word_id')
    meaning=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

admin.py:

```
def modified_output(self):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select word,meaning,id from meanings a,words b where a.word_id=b.word_id and meaning_id= "+str(self.id))
        row = dictfetchall(cursor)
        a=unicode(row[0]['word'])
        b=unicode(row[0]['meaning'])
        d=(row[0]['id'])
        return '%s  %s  %d ' % ( a,b,d)


meanings.add_to_class("__str__", modified_output)
```

Now for each row there is only 1 query running. But as the dependency on models have more than 2 tables in join of a query, it will still consume time. So my question is instead of running 1 query for each row, can we have the query result displayed directly for each page.

for example result of the following query on a page:

```
select * from table ;
```

instead of

```
select * from table when id=1;
select * from table when id=2;
.
.
.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`list_select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) option on the ModelAdmin to tell Django to do a JOIN query.

```
class MeaningAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_select_related = ('word_id',)
```

(Note, you really shouldn't call your FK fields things like `word_id`. The field gives access to an actual instance of Word, so it should just be called `word`; the underlying db column will automatically be called `word_id`.)

Comment: I didnt get where should your piece of code fits my requirement and what if I have to join multiple tables.

Comment: list_select_related is a tuple, so guess what to do for more then join. This goes into admin.py. It's not implemented on the model, as it doesn't belong on the model. Basically, `list_select_related` uses [query related tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#query-related-tools) to do the right thing.

Comment: what i need from join is word but not word id, i dont get how this helps my requirement

Comment: What does that mean? word_id is the foreign key that points to the word model, so this will give you that model. As I said, you should give your fields names that actually represent what they are, then this wouldn't confuse you.

Comment: Now i got what it mean.. but not getting how the same applies when there are multiple tables